# how to display data which is not old more then 10 second

Tags: sql

how can retrieve data which is inserted 10 second ago:

```
    string query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_getT WHERE Symbol=@Symbol AND (TIMEDIFF(current_timestamp, UntilValid)) > 10 ORDER BY ID asc ";
```

I need to show which is not old more than 10 seconds.

Comment: You can use `TIMESTAMPDIFF(current_timestamp, TIMESTAMP(UntilValid)) < 10` instead: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff, assuming the `UntilValid` is a `TIME` or `DATETIME` data type. If it's a `TIMESTAMP` data type, you can omit the `TIMESTAMP()` function.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (TIMEDIFF is a product specific function.)

Answer (score 0):

This can still make use of indexes

```
SELECT * 
FROM tbl_getT 
WHERE Symbol = @Symbol 
  AND UntilValid >= current_timestamp - interval 10 second
ORDER BY ID asc
```

Comment: Hello, I have tried not working:
SELECT * FROM tbl_DesoftAdvisorGetTrades WHERE Symbol = @Symbol AND UntilValid >= current_timestamp - 1 ORDER BY ID asc

still I got result, but in my case must empty result because is 10 secs ago.

Comment: Please add example data to your question. What data type does the `UntilValid` column have?

Comment: I have datetime